# Tymeleaf Empty th:value

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Trying to use th:each on a  element like following:

```
<select class="form-control" name="timeZone" required="true">
   <option th:each="t : ${timeZones}" th:value="${t}" th:text="${t}"></option>
</select>
```

But for some reason I am getting empty values attributes.

```
<select class="form-control error" name="timeZone" required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
                        <option value="">ACT</option>
                        <option value="">AET</option>
                        <option value="">AGT</option>
                        <option value="">ART</option>
                        <option value="">AST</option>
                        <option value="">Africa/Abidjan</option>
                        <option value="">Africa/Accra</option>
                        <option value="">Africa/Addis_Ababa</option>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your thymeleaf related code seems correct. However there are additional attributes applied (aria-required, aria-invalid, the class error) which means maybe there is some js code affecting your markup. I'd suggest to look at this direction

Comment: Also if I remove the <select> element and leave the <option> I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, if I use **th:attr** is fine.

```
<select class="form-control" name="timeZone" required="true">
   <option th:each="t : ${timeZones}" th:attr="value=${t}" th:text="${t}"></option>
</select>



<select class="form-control valid" name="timeZone" required="true" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                        <option value="AET">AET</option>
                        <option value="AGT">AGT</option>
                        <option value="ART">ART</option>
                        <option value="AST">AST</option>
                        <option value="Africa/Abidjan">Africa/Abidjan</option>
                        <option value="Africa/Accra">Africa/Accra</option>
                        <option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa">Africa/Addis_Ababa</option>
```